# How do I edit issues in Gitlab via the a API?

Tags: c#, api, gitlab, rest

I am trying to add a comment to a Gitlab issue via the API in a C# application.

The code below is as below:

```
  static async Task Test()
  {
        using (client)
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Private-Token", "TheToken");
            StringContent content = new StringContent(@"{\""body\"": \""newnote\""}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PutAsync("https://URL/api/v4/projects/1/issues/1/notes", content);
            string resultContentJson = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
  }
```

But it produces the following error:

> {StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content:
> System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:\r\n{\r\n  Connection:
> keep-alive\r\n  X-Request-Id: XXX\r\n
> X-Runtime: 0.002577\r\n  Date: Fri, 17 Sep 2021 15:07:23 GMT\r\n
> Server: nginx\r\n  Content-Length: 36\r\n  Content-Type:
> application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n}}

I assume I have done something wrong with setting the content but I cannot see what.
Anyone have any ideas?

Edit:

I have changed:

```
 StringContent content = new StringContent(@"{\""body\"": \""newnote\""}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

to

```
StringContent content = new StringContent(@"{""body"": ""newnote""}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Which is valid json.  It now produces the error message:

> {StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content:
> System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:\r\n{\r\n  Connection:
> keep-alive\r\n  Vary: Origin\r\n  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff\r\n
> X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN\r\n  X-Gitlab-Feature-Category:
> not_owned\r\n  X-Request-Id: XXX\r\n  X-Runtime: 0.012825\r\n
> Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n  Date: Fri, 17 Sep 2021 15:32:41 GMT\r\n
> Server: nginx\r\n  Content-Length: 25\r\n  Content-Type:
> application/json\r\n}}

Comment: Read the body of the response: there are 36 bytes of it, and it probably tells you what the error is

Comment: @canton7, nothing obvious - am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You haven't shown us what the response content is...

Comment: Your content is not valid JSON. You have the verbatim string modifier `@` *and* escape characters for quotes *and* double-double quotes. Try `Console.WriteLine(@"{\""body\"": \""newnote\""}");` and see what it shows you.

Comment: @TomW, good catch.  That has changed the reply but it still gives an error - I have updated the question

Comment: @canton7, the URL is to our self hosted gitlab repo.  It works with fetching results.  What have I done wrong with the Accept header?

Comment: The [GitLab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/notes.html#create-new-issue-note) say you use POST to create a new comment, and PUT to modify an existing comment. You're using the URL you'd use to create new comment, but using a PUT request.

Comment: @canton7, no worries - thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Are you sure you have a project whose id is `1` and within that an issue whose id is `1`? "404 NotFound" implies that it couldn't find that issue. Furthermore [the GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html) suggests that it expects issues to be addressed from the top level, not from under a project.

Comment: @canton7, that was it!!!  Thanks!  I changed from post to put earlier when trying to fix something else and forgot about it.  Thanks!

Comment: @TomW, the URL is obfuscated as I cannot put anything online about our internal servers etc.

Comment: Having said that, the `_links` collection does contain `"issues": "http://example.com/api/v4/projects/1/issues",` so I'm now not thinking this is necessarily a problem.

Comment: @canton7 since you answered the question with the "answer", please consider posting an answer so that it can be marked as an answer. (unless the OP wants to delete the question)

Comment: I'm not sure this would help anyone else, so I won't bother with an answer. OP can delete or self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was using

```
client.PutAsync
```

One should use:

```
client.PostAsync
```